# How to create window form inside custom tool window in visual studio 2015/2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins

I need to develop one extension for visual studio 2015 and 2017 where I need to provide login form which connects to some application server and upon login it will show all the services available in a treeview on visual studio . I already created it by the following way

custom command >>>  custom form(login) >> service tree form (list all services in tree view like eclipse package explorer)

But problem with above approach is that it opens new window in taskbar or in another way it looks like a different window altogether . This part i don't want. I want this functionality in custom tool window of visual studio so that it will not appear as new window or task.

Can anyone help me building the above scenario ?? Please note this has to support in visual studio 2015 on wards ..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about this issue? Could you get useful information from Hugo Quintela Ribeiro suggestion?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks for your response. I will give that a quick try and share the feedback asap.

Comment: I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Apologies for the delay. I have gone through the article shared , but it didn't help much. Facing too many difficulties implementing the feature which I have specified in the question. Can you share samples of treeview created on CustomToolWindow ? After goinh through some other articles noticed that most of use cases of treeview has implemented on a windows Form . I was just wondering how about inserting a form dynamically in custom tool window and adding treeview in that form and then dynamically adding nodes into it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the way to dynamically add treeview and add children to custom tool window.

Here is the way :

Following code snippet has been added to constructor of customtoolwindow controller class.

```
TreeViewItem treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
            treeItem.Header = "North America";

            treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "USA" });
            treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Canada" });
            treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Mexico" });

            TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
            treeView.Items.Add(treeItem);


            sampleStack.Children.Add(treeView);
```

where sampleStack is defined in respective .xaml file.

Comment: You could mark your solution as the answer. Thanks for your sharing. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Come on. This answer has nothing to do with developing extensions for Visual Studio. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

[Adding a tool window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx)